# Can I force ClassCleanup to execute in same thread as ClassInitialize?

Tags: c#

In the code snippet below I'm using ClassInitialize and Cleanup to wrap transactions around a series of tests I'm running. The code works in my GUI test runner but fails in mstest command line with the below error. Am I able to force Class cleanup and initialize to be in same thread? Prefer not to use Test initialize and cleanup as it will slow the test significantly.

**CODE**

```
        private static TransactionScope _trans;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        _trans = new TransactionScope();
        //...do work
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
        _trans.Dispose();
    }
```

**ERROR**

> *Run has the following issue(s): Class Cleanup method
>   GeoMetExplainSheetTests.TestCleanup failed. Error Message:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A TransactionScope must be disposed
>   on the same thread that it was created..*

Stack Trace:

> at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()

Comment: Found this post which highlights the calls to these methods on separate threads. Hmmm.. bummer... hope one of you out there has an answer for me!? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/17/explaining-execution-order.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace by removing `static modifier`

```
private TransactionScope _trans;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not possible as unfortunately ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup attributes need to be defined over methods that are static.